# Angularjs how to update view after a REST (delete) operation?

Tags: angularjs

here's my controller js

```
$scope.deleteField = function(f){
$http.delete('/fields/' + f.id )
  .success(function(){
    var index = $scope.fields.indexOf(f);
    $scope.fields.splice(index,1);
  });

};
```

here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Catalogue</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyCat" ng-controller="CatController" >

 <div ng-show="currentEntity==null">
 <div class="container spacer" >
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td><label>Nom Table:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="entity.entityName"></td>
       <td><button ng-click="saveTable()">Ajouter La table</button> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container spacer">
   <table class="table  table-hover spacer">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><button ng-click="deleteTables()">delete</button></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nom Table</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="t in entities track by $index" class="clickable" 
      ng-class="{active:currentEntity.id==t.id}" ng-click="showFields(t)">
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedEntities[$index].id" ng-true-value="{{t.id}}"/></td> 
       <td>{{t.id}}</td>
       <td>{{t.entityName}}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>  

   </table>
  </div>
   </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="container spacer"  ng-show="currentEntity!=null">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        Champs de la table {{currentEntity.entityName}}
        <button ng-click="viewTables()">Afficher Les tables</button>
        <button ng-click="view('structure')">Structure</button>
        <button ng-click="view('form')">Formulaire</button>
        <button ng-click="view('rows')">Rows</button>
    </div>
    <form ng-show="action=='structure'">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th><th>ID</th><th>Nom du Champs</th><th>Type</th><th>Relation</th><th>Input Type</th><td>Size</td><th>Primary</th><th>Index</th><th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="f in fields track by $index" class="clickable" 
      ng-class="{active:currentEntity.id==t.id}" ng-click="showFields(t)">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.fieldName"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.fieldType">
          <option ng-repeat="dt in datatypes" value="{{dt.id}}">{{dt.typeName}}</option>

          </td>


        <td> 
           <select ng-show="field.fieldType.id==6" ng-model="field.relation.id"> 
              <option value="null">----------</option> 
               <option ng-repeat="t in entities" value="{{t.id}}">
                {{t.entityName}} 
              </option> 
             </select> 
           </td> 
          <td>
            <select ng-model="field.inputType">
              <option value="text">text</option>
              <option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
              <option value="radio">radio</option>
              <option value="radio">select</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.size"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.primary"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.index"/></td>
          <td><button ng-click="saveField()">Save</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="f in fields"  track by $index" class="clickable" >

<!--            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedEntities[$index].id" ng-true-value="{{f.id}}"/></td>  -->
         <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.id}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.id" ng-show="f.editMode" /></td>
         <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.fieldName}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.fieldName" ng-show="f.editMode" /></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.fieldType.typeName}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.fieldType.typeName" ng-show="f.editMode"  /></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.relation.entityName}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.relation.entityName" ng-show="f.editMode" /></td>  
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.inputType}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.inputType" ng-show="f.editMode" /></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.size}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.size" ng-show="f.editMode" /></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.primary}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.primary" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.index}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.index" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>


          <td><button ng-click="deleteField(f)">delete</button></td> 

          <td><button ng-click="SaveEdits($index)" >saveEdits</button></td> 



        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container" ng-show="currentEntity!=null">
    <form ng-show="action=='form'">
      <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="f in fields">
          <td>{{f.fieldName}} :</td>
          <td ng-show="f.relation==null"><input type="{{f.inputType}}" ng-model="records[f.id].value"/></td>
          <td ng-show="f.relation!=null">

           <select ng-model="records[f.id].value" >
            <option ng-repeat="v in relations[f.id] track by $index" ng-value="{{v.id}}">
              {{v.id}}
            </option>
           </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
           <button ng-click="saveRecord()">Save</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" ng-show="currentEntity!=null">
    <form ng-show="action=='rows'">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th ng-repeat="f in fields">{{f.fieldName}}</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="r in rows track by $index">
           <td>{{r['id']}}</td>
           <td ng-repeat="f in fields track by f.fieldName">{{r[f.fieldName]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my java controller

```
package gen.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import gen.dao.FieldRepository;
import gen.dao.FieldValueRepository;
import gen.dao.RecordRepository;
import gen.dao.TableEntityRepository;
import gen.dao.TypeRepository;
import gen.entities.Field;
import gen.entities.FieldValue;
import gen.entities.Record;
import gen.entities.TableEntity;
import gen.entities.Type;
import gen.model.DataFieldValue;
import gen.model.RecordValues;

import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Fields;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DDLController {
    @Autowired
    private TypeRepository typeRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TableEntityRepository tableEntityRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FieldRepository fieldRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RecordRepository recordRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FieldValueRepository fieldValueRepository;
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveType")
    public Type saveType(Type t){
        typeRepository.save(t);
        return t;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getTypes")
    public List<Type> saveType(){
        return typeRepository.findAll();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveTable",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public TableEntity saveTable(@RequestBody TableEntity t){
        tableEntityRepository.save(t);
        return t;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getTables",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TableEntity> getTables(){
        return tableEntityRepository.findAll();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteTables",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean deleteTables(@RequestBody ArrayList<TableEntity> ids){
        System.out.println(ids.size());
        tableEntityRepository.delete(ids);

        return true;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveField")
    public Field saveNField(@RequestBody Field f){
        fieldRepository.save(f);
        return f;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteField")
    public boolean deleteNField(long id){
        fieldRepository.delete(id);
        return true;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/UpdateField")
    public Field UpdateNField(Field f){
        fieldRepository.saveAndFlush(f);
        return f;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getFields")
    public List<Field> getFields(TableEntity entity){
        System.out.println("**************");
        System.out.println(entity.getId());
        List<Field> fields=fieldRepository.findByEntity(entity);
        System.out.println(fields.size());
        return fields;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveRecord")
    public Record saveRecord(@RequestBody RecordValues values){
        System.out.println("---------------");
        TableEntity entity=new TableEntity();
        entity.setId(values.getEntityID());
        Record r=new Record();
        r.setEntity(entity);
        recordRepository.save(r);

        System.out.println("entityID="+values.getEntityID());
        for(DataFieldValue v:values.getRecord()){
            Field f=new Field();
            f.setId(v.getFieldID());
            FieldValue fv=new FieldValue();
            fv.setValue(v.getValue());
            fv.setField(f);
            fv.setRecord(r);
            fieldValueRepository.save(fv);
            System.out.println("FieldID="+v.getFieldID());
            System.out.println("FieldValue="+v.getValue());
        }
        return r;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllRecords")
    public Collection<Map<String,String>>getRecords(Long entityID){
        List<FieldValue> values=fieldValueRepository.getRecords(entityID);
        TableEntity e=new TableEntity();e.setId(entityID);
        //List<Field> fields=fieldRepository.findByEntity(e);
        Map<Long, Map<String, String>> records=new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, String> map2=new HashMap<>();
        for(FieldValue fv:values){

            if(records.get(fv.getRecord().getId())==null){
                map2=new HashMap<String,String>();
                map2.put("id", String.valueOf(fv.getRecord().getId()));
                records.put(fv.getRecord().getId(),map2);
            }
            map2.put(String.valueOf(fv.getField().getFieldName()), String.valueOf(fv.getValue()));
        }

        return records.values();

    }
}
```

i want to delete a single row from table but it doesn't work , the request works fine , the record is deleted from the database but  when clicking on delete it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML view code, especially data binding part?

Comment: Okay i will update the post

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is come from your indexOf.... maybe the best think is to work with $index.

**view**

```
<td><button ng-click="deleteField(f, $index)">delete</button></td>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.deleteField = function(f, index){
var fields = $scope.fields;
$http.delete('/fields/' + f.id )
  .success(function(){
    fields.splice(index,1)
    $scope.fields = fields;
  });
};
```

Comment: it doesn't work and when i click on delete ,i gives me an error on the console wich is : o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Comment: this problem is not come from the code i shared..., but from your backend server

Comment: Did you mean my java Controller where i have the crud operations? i don't think so because i test all the services and they work

Comment: i think... just comment the $http.delete inclusion lines and test

Comment: It works , that what i have done the first time but when i refresh , i find that the row is not deleted, i said that maybe i sould deleted from the server ,can you understand my problem?

Comment: oh yes, you row is not delete by your server, but your server don't show you any errors ?

Comment: now when i put the line that you ask me  in comment , i don't have any error .please help me , i am really blocked

Comment: I resolved the problem , thank you all , the problem want not my angularjs function but the url that i use in $http  and i change delete by get ant it works now

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as expected. Please verify your html as it has several issues. 
According to the comments from the post below please verify your java controller is accepting DELETE request. Probably you should change

```
$http.delete
```

to

```
$http.get
```

in order to make it work on client side (however it is just test solution but not prod one - this will mean that you have server issue)
Possibly this peace of working code will help

[fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/nesteant/dnvhc82h/)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <td>item {{item.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="deleteItem(item)">delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
     $scope.items = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
     $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {

     $http.get('/')
         .success(function() {
              var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
              $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: nesteant , it has nothing to do with html  because i can delete the row but the problem is when i refresh , it's not deleted so i have to delete the row from the server

Comment: I have just notified you about problems in html. Please check the part regarding $http.delete and $http.get

Comment: i will update the post to show you my java controller

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/deleteField") is not annotated as DELETE method. Please change it to @RequestMapping(value="/deleteField", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)

Comment: i change it but i still have request delete not  supported

Comment: I beleave your request was sent to /deleteField/someId where someId is id of your entity.
But in java controller you have only /deleteField resource. I think you should create next resource

@RequestMapping("/deleteField/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteNField(@PathVariable("id") long id)