# How to display angular page using @restcontroller?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to populate a dropdown with rest data which is annotated with `@RestController`.

From my understanding `@RestController` itself is annotated with `@ResponseBody` so I shouldn't try to return an angular view.  Is this correct?

So if this is the case what would you suggest?  Getting rid of `@RestController`?  Can `ngRoute` come into play here?  Should I use both `@Controller` and `@RestController`?

Comment: angular expects data but not view. You can use whatever solution, but it should return valid JSON. I.e. RestController can be used for data and Controller for serving templates

Comment: Ok.  The JSON being returned is valid.  There aren't many Angular Examples using Rest Controller.  Have you come across any?

Comment: you can look through the answer below and this thread. If you will have more questions I will answer in a separate comment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425321/angularjs-how-to-update-view-after-a-rest-delete-operation/30426789#30426789

Code is not perfect at all however it gives some understanding

Comment: Thank you.  Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Ah gotcha now. You want to mix json responses with html ones in the same controller, or you want to know whether this is a good idea.

It's up to you. I can see why you'd want to serve both types of responses from the same controller, especially when you only have a few method and perhaps don't want to separate out the notion of an api.

Just annotate the class with @Controller and annotate the json methods with the @RequestBody annotation and you can mix the two sorts of responses.

Comment: Robert.  My issue lies with showing the angular page itself from the spring controller.  It was using RestController but now I'm using Controller and ResponseBody.  My view resolver is set along with welcome file in web.xml.  How do I return to get the Angular view?  I can see the states results via localhost.  @RequestMapping(value="/states",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
 public String getStates() throws Exception{
  String result= dataManager.getStates();  
  return result;
 }